# Change height of status bar in android without root the device

Tags: java, android, permissions, operating-system, statusbar

I want to change statusbar height of android device using my application without give root access, Please let me know the solution

Comment: SO is not a helpdesk... show us some effort from your part to get to the answer.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow question checklist. You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).